# Puppeteer blank page when accesing URL

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

So I want to go to drpciv.ro and get some information .

Here is the code :

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto('https://www.drpciv.ro/');
  await page.screenshot({path: 'example.png'});
    
  let texts = await page.evaluate(() => {

    const elements = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('div.info-box-content'));
    return elements.map((div)=>div.innerText);
    
}); 
console.log(texts);
  await browser.close();
})();
```

When I output variable 'texts' ,  console shows that  variable is empty showing [] so I assumed that sites dosent load , and therefore cannot find the elements that I asked for.
I tried to make a screenshot in order to see if the page loads and it is blank .
Any help?

Answer (score 0):

That's because going to the url does not necessarily mean that the page has been loaded completely. Instead try adding an optional parameter waitUntil to the goto options, so that app will only resolve this promise after network has been idle for specified time.

```
await page.goto('https://www.drpciv.ro', {
    waitUntil: 'networkidle0' 
});
```

Please refer to the [official documentation page](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/api.md#pagegotourl-options) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

This was happening to me. Resolved after upgrade puppeteer to latest version.
If your puppeteer version is old, then the chrome version will be old and this means that some js methods could be not supported.